# XML Parsing in VBNet

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I'm trying to use VB.NET to extract the innertext from `<itemnote>` based upon the `name` attribute of `<series>` and the `name` attribute of it's child element `<item>`. I can extract the name attributes but I just can't access the innertext of `<itemnote>`

Here is some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
  <series name="HiTech" year="2000" country="United Kingdom">
    <item name="Robotic" collected="no">
    <itemnote>Exclusive UK Release</itemnote>
    </item>
     <item name="Future" collected="yes">
    <itemnote>LED Edition</itemnote>
    </item>
  </series>
  <series name="Neo" year="2003" country="United Kingdom">
    <item name="X Rated" collected="no">
    <itemnote>Red striped version</itemnote>
    </item>
     <item name="Cool Breeze" collected="no">
    <itemnote>Includes promo booklet</itemnote>
    </item>
  </series>
</Products>
```

So far I've tried using a recursive loop with XDocument but I've been unable to get anything more than a list of all the `<series>` and `<item>` attributes. I've also tried using XPath and Linq but I can't figure out how to make either of those do as I wish. Any help would be great! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the reference of `<item>` nodes and based upon `item` element, you can compare values of name attributes of `parent` and `child` element.

```
Dim nameOfSeries = "HiTech"
Dim nameOfItem = "Future"

Dim result = doc.Descendants("item").Where(Function(p)
                               Return p.Parent.Attribute("name").Value = nameOfSeries And 
                                                p.Attribute("name").Value = nameOfItem
                               End Function)

IF result.Count Then
  For Each ele In result
    Console.WriteLine(ele.Element("itemnote").Value)
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally got it working. I had been trying to get the `<series>` node and search through it's children.. No wonder nothing was working for me.